# Are British Prime Ministers forbidden from cycling?

Tags: united-kingdom, prime-minister

In [The Guardian, 'Cycling ambitions for England move up a gear with No 10 plans',](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2020/jul/27/cycling-ambitions-for-england-move-up-a-gear-with-no-10-plans?CMP=Share_AndroidApp_WhatsApp):

> Johnson is, famously, a keen city cyclist himself, even **if high office means he now has to be ferried about by car.**

I wasn't aware of any restrictions on who could cycle, nor do I know of any other reasons why Johnson "has to be ferried about by car".

I would otherwise think this relates to security, but "has to be" is a very strong formulation if it's only security that's the issue.

Comment: Boris was cycling today (but this probably doesn't count): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RhLQm60j3E

Comment: @fersarr: Given he left behind his helmet when he parked the bike, no it doesn't. :P The camera didn't show any security cycling with him though (I suspect they may have been further back or had cleared the area previously)?

Comment: Interest only: Churchill was persuaded by HRH not to watch the Normandy invasions from an offshore Battleship due to the risk to the nation if he was injured or killed. || I have seen photos of the not then yet current Pope on a commuter train in Buenos Aires and of Sergei Brin (replete with Google Glass) on a NY? subway. ||Best I've managed is meeting the then Deputy head of APEC on a Taipei subway platform (the lady I was with knew him - I'd not have recognised him).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, it's not *forbidden* per se, but as Joe C [mentioned](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/54873/28994), the security concerns of the Prime Minister cycling in London probably make it more trouble than it's worth. On the other hand, Johnson has often been [walking & jogging](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/11655324/boris-johnson-jog-coronavirus-battle/) in St James' Park since becoming PM.

This theory is, however, backed up by the Guardian, which [reported](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/dec/29/motorcycle-gift-puts-boris-johnson-back-on-his-bike) in December:

> He was forced to give up cycling around London when he became foreign
> secretary and then prime minister because of security precautions.

Forbes also [mentions](https://www.forbes.com/sites/carltonreid/2020/02/10/prime-minister-boris-johnson-pledges-5-billion-in-new-cash-for-buses-and-bicycle-infrastructure/#3858d2de6df6) that this has precedent:

> Like David Cameron, the previous bicycling prime minister, Johnson has
> had his wings clipped by security officials, and he is ferried around
> in armored cars rather than be allowed to cycle on London’s streets.

I would think that a large reason is that the optics of cycling while followed by an entourage of pool photographers, security, and advisors are not ideal, and the PM is probably trying to avoid a similar mishap as [befell](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-8328021/London-Mayor-Khan-gets-saddle-capitals-workers-told-ditch-public-transport.html) Sadiq Khan, the current Mayor of London, in May.

> London Mayor Sadiq Khan has been spotted out cycling in the capital
> today, closely followed by his security team in a £300,000 armoured
> car - after commuters were last week told to ditch public transport.
>
> [image]

Comment: @gktscrk Assuming that Forbes is right and neither Cameron nor Johnson were allowed, and I can't imagine May nor Brown cycling to be honest, a quick google finds Blair [cycling in Amsterdam](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk_politics/6615953.stm) at an EU summit just after becoming PM. That seems far too long ago to have been the last occasion though!

Comment: Could you clarify what Sadiq Khan's "mishap" is?

Comment: @JonathanReez The slightly embarrassing paparazzi photo of him being followed by his armoured Range Rover - in some ways defeating the environmental benefits of cycling. He is quoted in the article as saying: "By ensuring our city's recovery is green, we will also tackle our toxic air which is vital to make sure we don't replace one public health crisis with another."

Comment: @CDJB Cameron wasn't _forbidden_: he cycled to Parliament, but then his red despatch boxes followed in a car. This [was seen as hypocritical](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk_politics/4953922.stm) both when he cycled and when [he or other ministers walked](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/7809564/MPs-red-boxes-chauffeured-by-car-even-though-ministers-walk.html) while their briefcases were driven around.

Comment: @GrahamLee Interesting, but note also that your first article is from 2006, when Cameron was only Conservative leader. I can't find any evidence that this continued after  2010.

Comment: @CDJB: Could you edit the further information into the post?

Comment: It doesn't negate the *health* benefits of cycling ... except for the cyclists in the security vehicle's cloud of exhaust.

Answer (score 8):

It is down to security.

The car that the Prime Minister uses comes with a number of security features designed to protect the Prime Minister in the event of an attack, such as armour plating and bulletproof glass.  Needless to say, such protections are not available while cycling.

Comment: It's probably more down to the fact that a PMs schedule is incompatible with taking the bike everywhere. I am pretty sure he can still ride a bike recreationally, should he find the time.

Comment: Those protections also aren't available when he's out meeting the public or walking around which he obviously can do. I'm not sure there's a big difference there in the ability for him to be protected vs while he's cycling.

Comment: @gktscrk I would think that when meeting the public or walking around, he only does that at secure locations or at locations that have been secured previously by security forces. And it should be easier to secure the area were the PM is going to be if he restricts his movements to a few tens of meters than if the PM is going to do a 30 km ride.

Comment: @EikePierstorff That makes no sense, it's much faster to go around London cycling than driving.  He wouldn't be cycling to a meeting in Scotland.

Comment: I wonder how much worse the situation is in the UK if security is the main problem. The Dutch MP (Mark Rutte) is still cycling a lot of the time, even [in Afghanistan](https://indebuurt.nl/denhaag/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/anp-23555756-e1559728890893.jpg).

Comment: @EikePierstorff I would expect that a PM travel involves moving so much stuff and people (security, wardrobe, assistants) that I am pretty sure that transporting a bike would be negligible. Let's not forget that if he travels by air he "owns" the whole plane.

Comment: Might not be visible the world over, but not even walking is safe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FxcHVLmPgs (Former Australian PM being hugged while various implements are in the other hand)

Comment: @Mast That particular threat has receded but British standards around the security of personalities were shaped by events like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Mountbatten,_1st_Earl_Mountbatten_of_Burma#Assassination or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brighton_hotel_bombing

Comment: More than the lack of armour plating and bulletproof glass: if you're on a bike, on a public road, it is exceptionally easy for any would-be terrorist in a passing car to knock you down. I can't think of any way to defend against this without severely impacting traffic flows (which would be both unrealistic and politically untenable in a busy city such as London).

Comment: @Mast At least 2 recent U.S. Presidents have bicycled (Bush 2nd) and run (Clinton) around Washington, DC along with their security detachments, who "get" to bike or run along with them.  Either the security situation is (perceived to be) more dangerous for the PM now than for the President then, else the British protective services are lazier than the U.S. Secret Service.

Answer (score 5):

There's also the probability that the Prime Minister may hit someone while riding his/her bike. It would result in a big splash in the press.

This isn't outside the realm of possibility. I once hit a kid while I was out bicycling - he tripped and fell into the street in front of me.  Imagine what would result if that happened to a major government figure.

For example, the last time a Quebec premier (the head of the provincial government) drove his own car was when Rene Levesque was driving home from a party and [ran over](https://beverlyakerman.blogspot.com/2012/11/quebec-corruption-lets-not-forget-rene.html.) a homeless man sleeping on the street. Since then, it's been government limos all the time.

Comment: Although that _may_ be a reason for such a don't-cycle decision, it doesn't exactly make sense, pragmatically speaking. The chance of causing serious damage to citizens with the armoured limo, even though that's driven by a trained professional, is clearly much higher than with the personal bicycle. (Unless, I suppose, people deliberately jump in front of his bike to politically harm him.)

Comment: Ah, but the political harm that results from a career civil servant driver running over someone while chauffeuring around the PM is much less than the harm that would result from a PM-cyclist running over a kid.

Comment: It's certainly not without political harm either. I don't say you're wrong that the harm is less, but it really, really shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm not sure this is given the same amount of thought in the UK as the Queen and Prince of Edinburgh drive their own cars (at least on casual occasions). I don't know if the PM drives himself on casual occasions though...

Comment: @gktscrk A monarch hasn't been voted out of office in 370 years, so the political risk may be somewhat less of a concern to them.

Comment: Hey, he rugby tackled a kid, perhaps knocking one off a bike is just following his tradition!

Comment: @gktscrk The Duke of Edinburgh gave up his licence after a road accident last year, so he doesn't drive any more, at least on public roads. The Queen doesn't need a licence but may have decided to give up driving at the same time.